# Тире vs двоеточие. Кто победит?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильны ли оба варианта?

`У меня всё, что нужно для твоёго котчонка, есть, по-моему, – и лоток, и компот, и кисель, и коврижка, в мёд макáнная.`

`У меня всё, что нужно для твоёго котчонка, есть, по-моему: и лоток, и компот, и кисель, и коврижка, в мёд макáнная.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) *Да не надо ничего привозить. У меня всё, что нужно для твоёго котчонка, есть, по-моему, **– и лоток, и компот, и кисель, и коврижка, в мёд макáнная.***

Не надо ничего привозить, у меня **все есть.**  Присоединительная конструкция.

(2) *У меня всё, что нужно для твоёго котчонка, есть, по-моему: **и лоток, и компот, и кисель, и коврижка, в мёд макáнная.** Или еще что-нибудь надо?* Пояснительная конструкция, интонационное предупреждение.

У меня **вот что есть**. Или еще что-нибудь надо?